# How to replace obsolete knnclassify() function of matlab with the new fitcknn() function?

Tags: matlab, classification, knn

I have a sample matrix, training matrix and a group matrix. I have used the obsolete `knnclassify()` function. I would like to replace it with the `fitcknn()` function. I'm new to matlab. How does the `fitcknn()` method work and what are the changes that i need to make to make my code work? Screenshot attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlo6m.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is well described in the documentation, you should read it.

First train your model with your training dataset:

```
Mdl = fitcknn(TD,GT,'NumNeighbors',3); %TD = training dataset, Gr = ground truth
```

Then apply your model to your sample dataset:

```
Class = predict(Mdl,SD); %SD = sample dataset
```